# How to encrypt a code on python, where a string is encrypted into a secret code?

Tags: python, string, encryption

I am supposed to encrypt any string with a loop where some letters are change to special symbols, like a=@ e=() h=# l=1 and so on. I honestly have no idea how to do this. the function replace cannot be used. So far I have this but I know it is wrong.

```
 encryption(code):
    encrypted = ''
    for c in code:
        if c != '':
            a='@'
            e='()'
            h='#'
            l='1'
            r='+'
            s='$'
            v='^'
            x='*'
    return The encrypted code is:
```

Comment: What sort of data structure might you use to store a relationship between two strings?

Comment: it's just string replacements. to decrypt, you'd have `'@' = 'a'`

Comment: @Daniela - I noticed you tried to reply by editing an answer. The correct way to show that an answer is good or helpful is to vote it up using the up arrow in the left-hand column, and _accept_ it using the tick if it solves your problem, as outlined in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use replace? Perfect, because you should use `translate` instead.

```
def encrypt(cleartext):
    mapping = {'a':'@',
               'e':'()',
               'h':'#', ...}
    transdict = str.maketrans(mapping)
    enctext = cleartext.translate(transdict)
    return enctext
```

However I get the feeling that your instructor wants you to learn how to iterate over the cleartext, do a lookup for the correct value, and add it to an accumulator string. In pseudocode:

```
function encrypt(cleartext):
    encrypted = ""
    for each character in cleartext:
        if character == 'h':
            encrypted += "#"
        elif character == "a":
            encrypted += "@"
        ...
    return encrypted
```

I'd do something like:

```
def encrypt(cleartext):
    mapping = {'a':'@',
               'e':'()', ... }
    return ''.join(mapping.get(ch, ch) for ch in cleartext)
```

But if you turn that in without understanding it, I'm sure your teacher will fail you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def encryption(code):
    encrypted = ''
    for c in code:
        if c == 'a':
            encrypted = encrypted + '@'
        elif c == 'e':
            encrypted = encrypted + '()'
        elif c == 'h':
            encrypted = encrypted + '#'
        elif c == 'l':
            encrypted = encrypted + '1'
        elif c == 'r':
            encrypted = encrypted + '+'
        elif c == 's'
            encrypted = encrypted + '$'
        elif c == 'v'
            encrypted = encrypted + '^'
        elif c == 'x'
            encrypted = encrypted + '*'
        #here you can add other characters that need to be encrypted in elif blocks.
        else:
            encrypted = encrypted + c
    return encrypted
```

Comment: Giant `if..elif` blocks like this get unwieldy pretty quickly (and you missed a closing `'`).

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3 for pointing the missing quote. Yes, it's true that `elif` blocks aren't the nicest solution, but if you look at the code snippet in the question we can agree that any other shorter and nicer implementation, although will do the work, will probably be confusing. I simply converted the provided code into something that would work.

Comment: @Daniela: You probably wanted to add a comment, instead of editing the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
def encryption(text):
    if not text:
        return 'No text present.'
    encrypted = ''
    encryption_key = {'a':'@', 'e':'()', 'h':'#', 'l':'1',
                      'r':'+', 's':'$', 'v':'^', 'x':'*'}
    for c in text:
        encrypted += encryption_key.get(c, '?')
    return encrypted
```

Test:

```
>>> encryption('shell')
'$#()11'
>>> encryption('shellac')
'$#()11@?'
```